# Looking for a simple way to display a code block in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm looking for a way to display a block of code (i.e. show a snippet of markup) in Django admin. I've been digging around for a while, and my current (non-working) approach is:

```
from django.template import Context, loader

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'date')
    ordering = ('-date',)
    readonly_fields = ('markup',)

    def markup(self, instance):
        return create_markup(instance)

def create_markup(event):
    template = loader.get_template('event-markup.html')
    return template.render({'event': event})
```

The template 'event-markup.html' is simple, just something like:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ event.name }}</h1>
```

This seems close as it displays the template appropriately, but applies the styles:

[image]

Instead, I want it to show the source markup like so:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the output of your `create_markup` method.

```
from django.utils.html import escape

def create_markup(event):
    output = ...
    return escape(output)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much!